# "Use Recursion to Create a Countdown FreeCodeCamp"

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

why do they assign the function to the countArray var :

```
function countup(n) { 
   if (n < 1) {
     return [];  
 } else {  
   var countArray = countup(n - 1); // here
     countArray.push(n);  
   return countArray;
   }
 }
```

Comment: They're not assign the function but the returned value (which is array).

Comment: The call stack is unwinded `n - 1` times and the results are pushed into countArray, here is a reference - http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs1410/textbook/6.Functions/recursion.html

Comment: why does it return an array , is it because of the `.push()` or because of the _base case_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is a recursive function

It is a special kind of function, which is defined in terms of itself. For the simplest case, it gives a direct constant answer, in this case `[]`. But for more complex cases, it does something, and then calls itself to do a slightly simpler thing. That self-calling continues until the remaining task dwindles to nothing.

#### A common example of this function is the factorial function.

Factorial(n) is defined for positive integers `n` as:

```
If n is 1, the answer is 1, 
otherwise the answer is n * Factorial(n-1)
```

#### In your case, you are not returning numbers, but arrays

Why is it an array, because  of **both** the things you described!

The base case (n = 0) creates and returns an empty array, `[]`.
Any call with a higher n does the following:

```
Get the array for a one-lower value of n.
Push one more value onto the array
```

Since the only base value is [], and the only way it is mutated as you go up the chain is by `.push`, the result is always guaranteed to be an array.